# How to convert a numpy array of strings to a numpy array of sets to use MultiLabelBinarizer?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, encoding, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array like that:

```
l1 = (['United States', 'England', 'South Africa']).
```

Sometimes it could have >1 Value:

```
l1 = ([['United States','South Korea'], 'England', 'South Africa'])
```

I want to use MultiLabelBinarizer to encode these values. According to the documentation of *fit_transform*  in the scikit-learn documentation. The parameter should be

**y : iterable of iterables**
*A set of labels (any orderable and hashable object) for each sample. If the classes parameter is set, y will not be iterated.*

How can I convert this numpy array of list and single strings into sets?

I have tried this:

```
value = [set(v) for v in l1]
list_2sets = np.asarray(value)
```

But it seems it doesn't work properly.

The thing is that I do not have the values considered (all countries). If I had this, I tried the following which works:

```
 mlb.fit_transform(headings.split(', ') for headings in l1)
```

Being headings the list of all values considered:

```
['England','Spain', ...]
```

But I do not have those values so far, so I wanted to try applying MLB without '*headings*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to preprocess your array of strings as follows:

```
In [50]: l1 = [[x] if isinstance(x, (str)) else x for x in l1]

In [51]: l1
Out[51]: [['United States', 'South Korea'], ['England'], ['South Africa']]
```

For Python 2.x:

```
In [50]: l1 = [[x] if isinstance(x, (str, unicode)) else x for x in l1]

In [51]: l1
Out[51]: [['United States', 'South Korea'], ['England'], ['South Africa']]
```